# Given a list of Date ranges, how I do verify that all the days in a date range are covered in the list?

Tags: c#, java, date

I have a list of date ranges.

```
05/01/2012 - 07/01/2012
07/02/2012 - 09/05/2012
01/01/2012 - 03/31/2012
08/01/2012 - 12/31/2012
```

Now the problem is to verify whether the given list covers all the dates in a specific range. For ex, this list covers all the dates in range 05/01/2012 - 12/31/2012, but non 01/01/2012-12/31/2012 because April dates are not covered in this list. Assumptions are,

1. date range are valid - start date <= end date.
2. Date ranges may overlap as in the case of 2nd and 4th above.
3. List is not sorted in any way.

What I have so far is to test the outliers like,

> Finding the smallest start date and largest end date - If the start and/or end date of your test date range are less/greater than these dates respectively, test fails.

But what is the best strategy to check for any missed dates in the middle? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Smells like logic problem..

Comment: "proper - start date always <= end date" A crazy ordering. it's not little or big endian. ;)

Comment: What are the base objects of your dates? `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Also, are you only looking for day precision? Do you have any code?

Comment: How large can the range of dates get?  You could create a bit vector and start ticking off dates in ranges.  When you finish you should have a contigous block of 1s.  My guess would be sorting the ranges and then walking through comparing end vs. start will be pretty efficient.

Comment: @SonerGönül - ofcourse this is logic problem :) 

This is a common issue in dental insurance applications. If you are applying for Dental insurance, they will ask you if you have has insurance in last 12 months consecutively. If you do, then your new insurance can start right away. If you had any gaps in previous 12 months, then there will be a waiting period before your new insurance can start.  In the application, a user may add 3 or 4 previous insurance policies with effective date and termination date. That data becomes your list. 12 months becomes your test date range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is fix your input data.

1. Order all ranges by start date
2. Remove all overlaps by setting start dates
3. Eliminate any ranges that disappear due to 2

So your ranges would become

```
01/01/2012 - 03/31/2012
05/01/2012 - 07/01/2012
07/02/2012 - 09/05/2012
09/06/2012 - 12/31/2012
```

Then you just have to find the missing dates, see if you can figure out how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your steps
4). Find the starting and ending points for the test range.

5). See if any dates are missing in between.

For ex, if test range is 05/02-05/15, then starting and ending point is 2 - no gaps. If the test range is 03/15 to 06/01, starting point is 1, ending point is 2. There are 30 day gaps between 1's end date and 2's start date - so test fails.

Now I have to convert this to code.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest strategy is to parse all the dates involved. `O(N)`

Sort the dates by the starting date.  `O(N log N)` time

Compare the end date with the next start date (ignoring any end dates which go backwards) `O(N)`

If the one end to the next start date is more than a day you have a gap.

Comment: If you use Joda Time, there is actually a better one: grab the start date from the first element, check that for each element, `interval.endDate().plusDays(1)` is equal to the next element's start date. That is, if the OP wants day precision.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - Thanks for your answer. I think there is a small issue in the last step. If I am testing for all the days in range 05/01/2012-12/31/2012 in the given range it should pass but your last step says there is a gap which is incorrect. I think I need to do the steps described by @ Guvante before your last step.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dates to the number of days since 1 January 1970 (or some other reference date).

Then your problem becomes find the missing integers.

Comment: That depends on the granularity of what is searched... I don't think the OP wants millisecond precision.

Answer (score 0):

Generate every date in the ranges, put them in a list and test to see if your candidate is in that list.

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following (after sorting the list range by min date):-

```
  i=0
  a=min_date at 0 position
b=max_date corresponding to a

while list has elements
   c= min_date at (i+1) position
   d=max_date corresponding to c

if (b< (c - 1 day))
then there is a gap;
else 
{ 
if(b<d)   // done to handle the situation :- 06/07/2012 - 12/31/2012
          // 08/07/2012 - 11/31/2012. Then b will still remain 12/31/2012 after if condition
{
  b=d;
}
}
i=i+2;
end while;
```

The above will only find any missing date in the list.